# Python проверка: выполнялось ли действие сегодня

Tags: python, if

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно проверить, выполнялось ли определенное действие в течении текущего дня?

Код:

```
def get_messages_template(request) -> HttpResponse:
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return HttpResponseForbidden()
    tmpl_text = ''
    tmpl_id = id_cleaner(request.POST.get('template_id', ''))
    try:
        obj = MessageTemplate.objects.get(pk=tmpl_id)
        tmpl_text = obj.text
    except Exception:
        traceback.print_exc()

    return JsonResponse({'success': True, 'template': tmpl_text})
```

Мне необходимо проверить, отправлялось ли сообщение сегодня, и если да, то не отправлять его. Если же нет, то отправлять. Сообщение берётся из таблицы MessageTemplate.

Comment: Какое действие? Какое сообщение?

Comment: @dIm0n сообщение берётся из таблицы MessageTemplate

Comment: при отправке сообщения надо запомнить дату отправки и проверять эту дату при последующих попытках. Запоминать скорее всего удобно в БД (если она используется). Где конкретно хранить вопрос открытый. Если данное сообщение априори может отправляться только одному пользователю то можно в самой таблице с сообщением. Иначе, если пользователю может быть отправлено только одно сообщение - то в пользователе. Иначе, если любому пользователю может отправляться несколько разных сообщений (и сообщение может отправляться нескольким пользователям) - то в отдельной таблице: пользователь, сообщ, дата